# how to select all values of particular key from an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is the collection in MongoDB by the name- "auto_sales" and I want to select all the values of "sales" from data which is an array of object.

```
Collection-
{
"name" : "auto_sales", 
"data" : [ 
{ "sales" : 10, 
  "temp" : 50 }, 

{ "sales" : 9, 
"temp" : 51 }, 

{"sales" : 8, 
"temp" : 55 }, 

{"sales" : 57, 
"temp" : 7 }, 

{"sales" : 58, 
"temp" : 8 } 
] }
```

Is there any query to get all the values of "sales" from "data".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this one:

```
db.collection.find(
   {},
   { "data.sales": 1 }
)
```

gives

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e55400d22139e9b31aa786e"), 
    "data" : [
        {
            "sales" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "sales" : 9.0
        }, 
        {
            "sales" : 8.0
        }, 
        {
            "sales" : 57.0
        }, 
        {
            "sales" : 58.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Or rather this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         sales: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.sales"]] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      sales: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: "$$this.sales"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

gives

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e55400d22139e9b31aa786e"), 
    "sales" : [
        10.0, 
        9.0, 
        8.0, 
        57.0, 
        58.0
    ]
}
```

Comment: Good job! You can try the second query in this link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BlCF0jN6vuV

Comment: If you don't mind, can you post a map-reduce version of this answer?

Comment: @bravemaster actually I never used map-reduce yet - so it would be a challenge for me.